# How to generate a fixed width file with different data types in each row in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I want to find out if there is a better way to present a data the way I need using T-SQL and generating a TEXT file in SSIS from SQL command(Exec stored proc).

So I need to present a data in a text file with fixed width for each column, like col1 - 10 alphacharacters, col2 numeric with zero pads, col3 blanks etc.
the Total number of characters in a line cannot exceed and must be 275.

However Each Row is going to have different data and different column requirements.
So if

- First row: '1', col1 - 22 alphacharacters, col2 numeric with zero pads 10 characters, col3 blanks(fill up to 275)
- Second row:'2', col1 - date 6 characters,col2 3 blanks
  col3 30 alphacharacters, col4 numeric, col 5 blanks(fill up to 275)

What I come up with is to concat the row into 1 big string and then Union ALL the rows.

And in SSIS I do Ragged right without columns headers and the text file is coming up exactly as I want, but I wonder if there is a better way to do that

I Figured how to manipulate data with different functions, so i'll just present a code without them to make everything simple

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('1',COL1, COL2, REPLICATE(' ',n...)) as 123
FROM MYTABLE

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT('2',COL1,REPLICATE(' ',3),COL2, COL3, REPLICATE (' ',n..)) as 123
FROM MYTABLE2
```

The Layout of results should look like that in a text file (I just put random data for this example to make visualization better)

```
1Microsoft SQL Server  0000002017
208202019   John Doe                      00000015
208202019   Jane Doe                      00000109
208202019   Will Smith                    00001996
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rephrasing your task - you need to set a custom header for your Flat File, and output sows in Ragged format.
The alternative approach is the following. Create a string variable and fill it with header row data as desired. On the *Data Flow task* which fills in the *Flat File Destination*, locate `[Flat File Destination].[Header]` property and set its expression to the string variable from above. This will create a file with defined header. Then on the data flow itself - create a string computed column where you format your output string, and later - save this column into the *Flat File Destination*.
This is more SSIS approach, since you do not have to do complex SQL statements.